# Inno Setup Procedure not executing after install

Tags: installation, inno-setup, setup-deployment

I have compiled multiple programs in inno setup i.e

1. Sql Server
2. .Net framework 3.5
3. Crystal Reports
4. Sql Script

the problem i am facing is that the procedure in which the code of executing the script is present does not execute after the installation of a program before it. If the program before it is cancelled then it execute.

```
[Files]

Source: "E:\Inno Data\Inno_Setup\Prerequisites\dotnetfx35\NDP451-KB2858728-x86-x64-AllOS-ENU.exe"; DestDir: {tmp}; AfterInstall: InstallFramework
Source: "E:\Inno_Setup\Prerequisites\CrystalReports105\CRRuntime_64bit_13_0_5.msi"; DestDir: {tmp}; AfterInstall: InstallCrystalReports

Source: "E:\Prerequisites\SQLServer2008R2SP2\SQLEXPRWT_x64_ENU.exe"; DestDir: {tmp}

;SQL Script Files
Source: "E:\SQLInstallTEST\Scripts\RCabSoft.sql"; DestDir:"{app}\Scripts"

[Run]

Filename: "{tmp}\SQLEXPRWT_x64_ENU.exe"; Parameters: "/ACTION=Install /INSTANCENAME=MSSQLSERVER /QS /HIDECONSOLE /INDICATEPROGRESS=""False"" /IAcceptSQLServerLicenseTerms /SQLSVCACCOUNT=""NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM"" /SQLSYSADMINACCOUNTS=""builtin\users"" /SKIPRULES=""RebootRequiredCheck"" "; Check: isWin64(); 
Filename: "msiexec.exe"; Parameters: "/i ""{tmp}\CRRuntime_64bit_13_0_5.msi"" /qb"; WorkingDir: {tmp}; 
Filename: "{tmp}\NDP451-KB2858728-x86-x64-AllOS-ENU.exe"; parameters: "/SILENT /NOCANCEL"; AfterInstall: sqlscript;

[Code]

procedure sqlscript;
var
  ResultCode: Integer;
  OutputText: String;
begin

      if FileExists(ExpandConstant('{pf32}\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\VSShell\Common7\IDE\SSMS.exe')) then
      begin        
        ExtractTemporaryFile('RCabSoft.sql');        

        // Execute SQL Update Scripts        
          Exec('SqlCmd.exe', ' -e -E -S .' + ExpandConstant(' -i "{tmp}\RCabSoft.sql"'), '', SW_SHOW, ewWaitUntilTerminated, ResultCode);         
      end;                                                      
end;
```

Comment: First off, you should check whether those prerequisites are not already installed on the target system. Then, if you want to interrupt their installation chain, do it in script code (the only way I can think of is checking the exit code of the just executed setup), ideally from the `PrepareToInstall` event method.

Comment: @TLama.... well i have pasted the required code....the checks are in the real code....but the main problem is that the procedure is not executing...

Comment: Sorry, I did not get your question on the first read. Do you mean that the `sqlscript` procedure does not execute ? I'm still a bit lost from the order of actions that you described. In any case, you should check the result of the `Exec` function call as well as the exit code that it returns. From what I can say for now, you are missing path to the `SqlCmd.exe`.

Comment: I´m facing the same problem. Theres some solution found?