# Unable to Execute File: CreateProcress Failed; Code 87.The Paramete is incorrect

Tags: inno-setup, setup-project

i have made a setup in which my function is directly run in [Run] section. This setup runs the database script. It runs fine but when it completes it throws "Unable to Execute File: CreateProcress Failed; Code 87.The Paramete is incorrect".

What is causing this error and how to fix it?

My inno code:

```
[Files]
Source: "E:\SQLInstallTEST\Scripts\RCabSoft.sql"; DestDir: {app}; Flags: ignoreversion

[Run]
Filename: "{code:SqlScript}";

[Code]

function SqlScript(Value: string): string;
var
  ResultCode: Integer;
  OutputText: String;

begin

        if FileExists(ExpandConstant('{pf32}\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\VSShell\Common7\IDE\SSMS.exe')) then
            begin        
              ExtractTemporaryFile('RCabSoft.sql');        

              // Execute SQL Update Scripts        
                Exec('SqlCmd.exe', ' -e -E -S .' + ExpandConstant(' -i "{app}\RCabSoft.sql"'), '', SW_SHOW, ewWaitUntilTerminated, ResultCode);         
                MsgBox('Successful', mbInformation, MB_OK);          
       end;
end;
```

SnapShot:

[image]

Comment: Your parameters to `Exec` are wrong. To see why, add a Temp string variable declaration and these two lines of code: `Temp := ' -e -E -S .' + ExpandConstant(' -i "{app}\RCabSoft.sql"'); MsgBox(Temp, mbInformation, MB_OK);` and inspect what is shown in the popup.

Comment: Also, it's not appropriate (or acceptable) here to ping a specific user for help. It actually doesn't work, unless that user has commented or answered this specific question. Please don't clutter the site by doing so.

Comment: @KenWhite...thanks for the point...i will delete the comment

Comment: @KenWhite...can you please explain the code in detail which you sent in comment

Comment: @KenWhite the point is my code execute but when the script finishes then it throws this error..the code works fine

Comment: I don't think your code is executing, because you don't specify where SQLCmd is located (SQL Server's binaries are not usually placed on the Windows PATH).  You're also not checking the result of `Exec()` (which is true if it succeeds, false if not), so you don't know if it worked or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you're not actually returning a string from the SqlScript function, i.e. you're not writing to the built-in `Result` variable.

Also, you should use either `[Run]` or `Exec`, but not both, as both as meant to run an executable.

*(From my comment below)* Try this in the `[Run]` section:

```
Filename: "SqlCmd.exe"; Parameters: "-e -E -S . -i {app}\RCabSoft.sql"; Check: FileExists(ExpandConstant('{pf32}\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\VSShell\Common7\IDE\SSMS.exe'))
```

and remove the SqlScript function completely.

Comment: There is no result from running the SQL Script, so there is nothing to return. It should actually be just a procedure instead of a function.

Comment: @KenWhite how to execute a procedure directly...??

Comment: Basically, you should use either `[Run]` or `Exec`, but not both. Try this in the `[Run]` section: `Filename: "SqlCmd.exe"; Parameters: "-e -E -S . -i {app}\RCabSoft.sql"; Check: FileExists(ExpandConstant('{pf32}\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\VSShell\Common7\IDE\SSMS.exe'))` and remove the `SqlScript` function completely.

Comment: tried the code above but no response it starts the progress bar and ends it immediately.

Comment: @sschuberth, you are correct with this answer. But your suggestion will work as long as the sqlcmd.exe is *registered* between `PATH`s. Which I think is not (I've tried to guess that [`here`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29771382/inno-setup-procedure-not-executing-after-install#comment47674287_29771382) with no further response). Also the parameters passed to the tool are suspicious.

Comment: Right. But as the OP said "It runs fine [...]" I was assuming the `Exec` actually succeeds and `SqlCmd.exe` is in `PATH`.

Comment: @sschuberth...i have made two setups the first installs the sql server in silent and when that setup is competed it executes the 2nd setup automatically which executes the scrip. After installation of SQL SERVER when the script setup is executed it throws and exception 
"Unable to execute file: 
SqlCmd.exe
CreateProces failed; code 2.
The system cannot find the file specified."

Any solution for it..??

Comment: I'm not sure where the `SqlCmd.exe` comes from. But if you run it without specifying a path to that file, the file needs to be in a directory that is listed as part of your `PATH` environment variable, i.e. it needs to be discoverable system-wide.

Comment: @sschuberth.....when i run it in "/silent" from another setup then it throws this error.